# JTextfield and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I have created a JFrame with 3 JTextFields, a button and a label in the centre of the page. I will create a key where if the user enters 'a' in all three textfields and hits the button, the color of the text in the label should change to a different colour for example red.

The main problem I have is linkning my textfields and the button so they work together.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class CE203_2017_Ex1 extends JFrame

{
     public static void window()
        {
            //Button
            JButton but  = new JButton("Submit");
            //JNumberTextField
            JTextField rgb1 = new JTextField("",3);
            JTextField rgb2 = new JTextField("",3);
            JTextField rgb3 = new JTextField("",3);
            //JLabel
            JLabel text1 = new JLabel("hello my name is adam ", JLabel.CENTER);
            text1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            text1.setAlignmentX(0);
            text1.setAlignmentY(0);
            //JFrame
            JFrame window1 = new JFrame("Adam");
            window1.setVisible(true);
            window1.setSize(500,500);
            window1.add(text1);
            //JPanel
            JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();
            butPanel.add(rgb1);
            butPanel.add(rgb2);
            butPanel.add(rgb3);
            butPanel.add(but);

            window1.add(butPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            window1.add(text1);
```

Here is my actionlistener for the button

```
 but.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JTextField input = (JTextField) e.getSource();
                    String passy = input.getText();
                    String p = new String (passy);

                    if (rgb1.equals("a")&& rgb2.equals("a")&& rgb3.equals("a")){
                        text1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nocorrect");}}});
          }
     public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            window();

        }
}
```

Comment: Have you copied your code wrong? Your main method is inside the ActionListener and your window() method is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You want to test the text value in the textFields not the objects.

```
if (rgb1.getText().equals("a")&& rgb2.getText().equals("a")&& rgb3.getText().equals("a")) {
    text1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}
```